# Programatic navigation on authentication SwiftUI with Publishers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, navigation

I have this code for authentication in a SwitUI application. `SessionStore` is an observable object which is injected into the main entry point of the app. When the sign is success then navigate to the dashboard. The `isLogin` variable changes but redirect does not happen. I don't understand what am not doing wrong.

// Main View

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var session = SessionStore()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            SplashScreenView()
                .environmentObject(session)
        }
    }
}
```

// Splashscreen view which redirects to sign in or dashboard

```
struct SplashScreenView: View {
    
    @StateObject var session = SessionStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if session.isLogedIn {
                DashboardScreen()
            } else  {
                SignInScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Session Store

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var session: User?
    @Published var profile: UserProfile?
    @Published var isLogedIn = false
    
    private var profileRepository = UserProfileRepository()
    
    func signUp(email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, city: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error signing up: \(error)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            print("User (user.uid) signed up.")
            
            let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: user.uid, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, city: city)
            self.profileRepository.createProfile(profile: userProfile) { (profile, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                self.profile = profile
                completion(profile, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ profile: UserProfile?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [self] (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error signing in: \(error)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let user = result?.user else { return }
            print("User \(user.uid) signed in.")
            self.isLogedIn = true
            self.profileRepository.fetchProfile(userId: user.uid) { (profile, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error while fetching the user profile: \(error)")
                    completion(nil, error)
                    return
                }

                self.profile = profile
                completion(profile, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signOut() {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            self.session = nil
            self.profile = nil
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print("Error signing out: \(signOutError)")
        }
    }
}
```

// In my view I call the method and update the log-in status or sign up. Which changes the state but does not redirect

```
struct SignInScreen: View {
    @ObservedObject var sessionStore = SessionStore()
var body: some View {
Button(action:signIn, label: {
                        Text("Sign In")
                    })
 }

    func signIn() {
        loading = true
        error = false
        sessionStore.signIn(email: signInViewModel.emailAddress, password: signInViewModel.password) { (profile, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error when signing up: \(error)")
            return
          }
            sessionStore.isLogedIn = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I'm trying to do something similar. Can you tell me what's the difference between your published variables: `session: User?` and  `profile: UserProfile?` declarations? I mean, what are you storing in each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using firebase. If you need to check authentication status it would be easy to do it this way.

Your main entry view

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var session = SessionStore()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            SplashScreenView()
                .environmentObject(session)
        }
    }
}
```

In your session store add this code to check if the current is signed in using `FirebaseAuth` and not doing it manually.

```
class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
   
   // Previous code 
    var isSignIn: Bool {
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil
    }

}
```

In your splash screen check for `isSignIn`.

```
struct SplashScreenView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if session.isSignIn {
                DashboardScreen()
            } else  {
                SignInScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ObservedObject` instead of `EnvironmentObject`? (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject)

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva `@ObservedObject` for complex properties that might belong to several views. Most times you’re using a reference type you should be using @ObservedObject for it. While `@EnvironmentObject` for properties that were created elsewhere in the app, such as shared data. In this case is authentication which all the app modules will be watching the state.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore instead of @StateObject in SplashScreenView.

Comment: I made the modification as suggested still same.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ObservedObject` instead of `EnvironmentObject`? (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/whats-the-difference-between-observedobject-state-and-environmentobject)

Comment: No. ObservedObject = StateObject, and StateObject is already used.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to have only one instance of your SessionStore().
Here, you redefined it twice: @StateObject var session = SessionStore()

In your MyApp, do

```
@StateObject var session = SessionStore()
```

and in others views, do

```
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
```

and, you forgot to pass your environmentObject to your SignInScreen

```
.environmentObject(session)
```

Comment: You can combine the first and third lines of code and just write `.environmentObject(SessionStore())`.